# Reasons for having ids in URL

Tags: restful-architecture, restful-url

I have seen sometimes in applications when you're doing a get request for example, URL is:

```
www.baseurl.com/thing/{{ID}}
```

Sometimes there is no representation of the restful action in the URL. In my current job for example, the URL never changes. This is probably because we are not following single page application principles.

So on a get the URL would not change at all, and would be either:

```
www.baseurl.com/
```

Or

```
www.baseurl.com/thing
```

A few questions:

1. What is the architectural pattern name for the URL with the ID in it?
2. Is it RESTful?
3. What are the pros and cons?
4. If it's RESTful what are the benefits to doing it this way, across http requests?

Comment: The action in a RESTful system is generally denoted by the HTTP verb being used(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc)

Comment: Hmm true. So what exactly is represented in the URL in the first example? Which object is being interacted with?

Comment: REST in itself is an architectural style. Representation of a URL in REST does not rely **ONLY** on the url but a combination of the url and the Http verb used.

E.g. `www.baseurl.com/thing/{{ID}} with GET -> implies read of 'thing' resource with a given ID. www.baseurl.com/thing/{{ID}} with DELETE -> implies deletion of 'thing' resource with the given ID`

Comment: So the appropriate URL must be there in order to follow good rest architecture?